# Reset ram usage in google colab after training a neural network

Tags: keras, deep-learning, ram

I am training in leave one-out validation a neural network.
At the end of every session of training in google colab pro+ the ram is not resetting and when I start the next training I have already busy 20gb of ram.
[image]

Someone know how can I reset the ram at the end of the training?
I was thinking of using

```
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K
K.clear_session()
```

but is not working